# Trying to check for a key,value pair in a list of lists in Ocaml

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, nested-loops

I am trying to see if a name exists in a list of lists, and if it does i will return the value associated with the name. I am binding values(strings, ints, bools) to a string and storing them in an environment which is represented by each list in the overall list.

```
let rec lookup key envlist = 
  match envlist with
  | [] -> None
  | hd::tl -> lookupaux key hd
in

let rec lookupaux name curenvlist = 
  match curenvlist with
  | [] -> None
  | (n,v)::t -> 
    if n = name then Some v 
    else lookupaux name t
```

i know that this is invalid, but this is what i have come up with so far. any help would be awesome. also, I am trying to read the whole top row first, then the next row and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The iteration logic is good, but I don't understand the need for two functions?
In the [List module of OCaml](https://ocaml.org/api/List.html), there are functions that could help you. For example, there are some functions in the OCaml List module that might help you, for example, since `OCaml 4.10.0` you can use [`find_map`](https://ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALfind_map):

```ml
let lookup searched_key envlist = 
  List.find_map (fun (key, value) ->
     if key = searched_key then Some value else None
  ) envlist
```

Or we use `find_opt` which is less direct but has the merit of being around longer (`OCaml 4.05`) :

```ml
let lookup searched_key envlist = 
  (* First, get an option *)
  List.find_opt (fun (key, _) -> key = searched_key) envlist
  (* Now, using Option, you can fetch only the value 
     https://ocaml.org/api/Option.html#VALmap (since 4.08) *)
  |> Option.map snd
```

(Of course, you can manually deconstruct your resulted option in order to not depend on the module Option, if you use an older OCaml's version).

On the other hand, if you really want to build the manual recursion, it is also, obviously possible, by following a scheme close to the one you have proposed:

```ml
let rec lookup searched_key envlist = 
   match envlist with 
   | [] -> None
   | (key, value) :: tail ->
       if key = searched_key then Some value 
       else lookup searched_key tail
```

You can also use `when` (guards) for having the condition at the pattern level:

```ml
let rec lookup searched_key envlist = 
   match envlist with 
   | [] -> None
   | (key, value) :: _  when key = searched_key -> Some value
   | _ :: tail -> lookup searched_key tail
```

But if you look at the code, you may be annoyed that you have to repeat through the recursion the key you are looking for... even though it is constant at the execution of the function? So we can use an auxiliary function, internal to our function, to avoid having to pass the key each time.

```ml
let lookup searched_key = 
   let rec aux = function
   | [] -> None
   | (key, value) :: _  when key = searched_key -> Some value
   | _ :: tail -> aux y tail
   in aux (* [aux] will return a function that take a list *)
```

**EDIT:**

I had missed the point that you have to find a key in a list of lists and now, I understand why did you need two function.
Here is something pretty close of your suggestion.

```ml
let lookup searched_key = 
   let rec find_value = function
     | [] -> None
     | (key, value) :: _  when key = searched_key -> Some value
     | _ :: tail -> find_value y tail
   in 
   let rec aux = function 
     | [] -> None 
     | x :: xs -> begin 
        (* begin/end or parenthesis are mandatory for 
           nested pattern matching *)
        match find_value x with 
        | None -> (* if we don't find the key, we continue on the tail*)
           aux xs
        | Some x -> Some x
     end
     in aux
```

I think the only mistake your program made was that it didn't check that a value had been found in the list. So it iterate through the list, even the key was found. You just has to treat the case when you find something (or not). Like in my code.

**Second edit**
Using the form `f = function ...` can be unclear so here is a version without shortcuts:

```ml
let lookup searched_key envlist = 
   let rec find_value list = 
     match list with
     | [] -> None
     | (key, value) :: _  when key = searched_key -> Some value
     | _ :: tail -> find_value y tail
   in 
   let rec aux envlist = 
     match envlist with
     | [] -> None 
     | x :: xs -> begin 
        (* begin/end or parenthesis are mandatory for 
           nested pattern matching *)
        match find_value x with 
        | None -> (* if we don't find the key, we continue on the tail*)
           aux xs
        | Some x -> Some x
     end
     in aux envlist
```

Comment: i just want to make sure i am checking the first list in envlist for the key first and then check the next list. for visual representation i would show like this [[(x,y);(x,y))];[(a,b);(a,b)]]...i want to check the (x,y)'s and then check (a,b)'s. your solutions may solve that issue but i am not following that logic. I appoligize that i cannot see it, i don't see where it iterates down the list of environments

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't understand properly your goal. So if you find the value in the first list, you don't check the rest?

Comment: that is correct. the environments represent different scopes. if it is not in the first scope, check the next scope above and so on. for example in C, it would be nested for loops iterating left to right in the nested loop and top to bottom in the outer loop...breaking out when i find the key, if it exists and returning the value

Comment: I have edited my message (and I add an "edit" block on the bottom with a suggested implementation, pretty close of yours). Is that good for you?

Comment: i understand how the function iterates, but i fail to see where you pass in an envlist as an argument. sorry i am new to Ocaml. Thank you for the fast responses!

Comment: Oh it is because `f = function ...` is a shortcut for `f x = match x with ....`  so `aux` (and `find_value`) are function that take list, so if i just return `aux` I return a function which await for the list. I could rewrite it like `let rec aux l = ... in aux l`

Comment: I just add a new edit, with a version using match and being explicit on passing arguments. Is that clearer?

Comment: do i have to put the envlist argument after searched_key before the equal sign? This lookup function is a helper function to a bigger program. If I call lookup with the key and the envlist, does the argument for envlist get passed into the function and  "picked up" by aux or find_value?

Comment: I added a new edit (the last I guess) with an explicit version. There is no "implicit" here. `find_value` is a function which take a list, and `aux` is a function which take a list of list. So you have to call it like `lookup my_key my_list`